# How to create a custom in-app notification in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

In Salesforce lightning I see a bell icon in the top right corner which displays notifications. I have a custom object and I would like to know if it is possible  to create a notification inside Salesforce when the record value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a task whenever a record is getting changed on the desired object. Task will help you to get notified whenever a record is changed

Creating task based on record change can be done using apex triggers.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tasks_enable_task_notifications.htm&type=5